# Can I use frequently change code in Google Wallet?

Tags: android, google-wallet

So my task is to determine whether we can integrate Google Wallet or not.

Every user has a unique QR code, but this code changes every time.
This code can change for example if the code expires, or the user uses it for the first time.

Our code generation process is also complicated, because it has a lot of secure parameter as well as some user inputs.

I watched the video about the implementation, but it seems, we can use it only just with a constant code, or otherwise I need to change the saved Passes object from my application.

Expected behavior would be, that the users set up the wallet from our application for the first time, but after that they should not use our application to get the fresh code.

So I don't know. Am I missed something, or it is not feasible?